# Flink disableOperatorChaining Performance impact

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I need to understand if i disable operator chaining or start a new chain, what will be the impact on the job performance.

i want to disable it just to follow the job in the webUI. So wanna know how it will impact the job performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Task chaining/Operator chaining brings one or more tasks into a single thread which reduces the impact of the de/serialization of the records that travel around your streaming flow.

Example would be better to understand:

- Let's say you have 2 operators one for mapping other for filtering (map -> filter) and flink brings instances of 2 operators into a single thread.
- When one record comes to the map instance, after the map function is done, filter function will be directly called(simple method calling) without serialization and deserialization operations.
- If you disabled chaining, then record could not be passed directly to the other operation. Therefore this would lead to the bad performance impact

However, sometimes disabled chaining could be a better solution. Not: I have deleted my example for this situation, because @DavidAnderson stated that it was not correct. My basic point was that there could be situation which chaining operation would cause some instances to be idle.

Comment: Operator chaining is only applied when the two operators have a data forwarding connection. In your example where the parallelism is changing between the map and the filter, operator chaining isn't possible, so there's no need to disable it.

Comment: @david So can you give example when is the need to disable it. When it will be useful to disable chaining without any job performance impact.

Comment: Disabling operator chaining can be useful for debugging or demos, because it makes the communication between operators more observable. It might be useful in production if you have an operator that you need to isolate because it uses a library that isn't thread-safe -- but then you'd also need to disable slot sharing.

Comment: Hey, I have encountered a situation like this one: my kafka and my map operation have 16 parallellism. However, my kafka topic has 8 partitions and flink only uses 8 instances of kafka operation and also flink uses 8 instances of map operation. After disabling chaining operation, flink started to use all map instances.

Comment: @DavidAnderson What about for situations where you have, for example, two tasks which are both compute heavy, or have large state that can sometimes be expensive to load/update? It seems like in those situations, you may benefit from decoupling them with some sort of intermediate buffer. However, you don't necessarily want to take the overhead of the network transfer when they can be processed in the same slot.

Is there some way to keep them both local, but move them into separate threads? It seems like the answer is "no", at least with them implemented as separate process functions.

Comment: @Ken You can have two such operators in the same slot and disable chaining so that they are assigned to different tasks (and thus each have their own thread). Because they are still in the same slot Flink's network stack will use shared memory rather than netty for communication, but you'll still have to pay for ser/de.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Thanks for the tip. I just tried this out and it appears the bigger downside to this (for our workload at least) is that the JM needs to track and assign out these tasks separately, so that adds quite a bit of overhead for orchestration if you're already running a very large workload. That issue aside, though: the network buffer should at least be significantly more efficient, yes? As opposed to needing network buffer space to accommodate the N upstream sub-tasks, you only need to buffer messages for one. If your network buffer is already quite large, that should be a no-op.