# How to have one operator per vertex in Apache Flink?

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a streaming job that I am running in Apache Flink.

It consists of the following operators:

1. Source Function (generates data)
2. Filter Function (filters out some data)
3. GroupBy and aggregate (groups data based on a key and then runs an aggregation function over them)
4. Another filter function
5. File Sink (saves output to file)

However, when I sumbit the job I get the following graph.
[image: Query Graph - Flink UI]

As you can see for example the 3rd and 4th steps are merged together.
My question is, since I want to measure the throughput and latency of each step, is there a way to split each operator on its own vertex? In this example: Have a node for the groupBy-Aggregation and another one for the filter function (endsWith).

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with

```java
env.disableOperatorChaining();
```

However, you should expect this to degrade performance, perhaps significantly. See [Flink disableOperatorChaining Performance impact](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62933685/2000823) for more about this.